# ¿Cómo contar números de pagina con CSS?

Tags: html, css

trato de poner un contador de paginas en mis reportes de pdf, del tipo "1 de N".

**MI CSS:**

```
.page-number:after { 
    content: "Página " counter(page) " de " counter(pageTotal);
}
```

**EL ELEMENTO HTML DONDE LO LLAMO:**

```
<thead style="font-size:10pt;">
   <tr>
      <td rowspan="4" style="width:153px;text-align:center;height:80px;border: 1px solid black;"><img src="" width='85%'></td>
      <td rowspan="4" colspan="2"style="width:401px;background-color:#D8D8D8;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;height:80px;border: 1px solid black;">COTIZACION DE SERVICIOS</td>
      <td colspan="2" style="width:161;height:20px;border: 1px solid black;"></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
       <td colspan="2"style="height:20px;border: 1px solid black;"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td colspan="2"style="height:20px;border: 1px solid black;">FECHA: 2022-02-02</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td colspan="2"style="height:20px;border: 1px solid black;" class="page-number"></td> 
   </tr>
   <tr>
        <td colspan="5" style="border-left-color: white;height:4px;"></td>
   </tr>
 </thead>
```

**MI RESULTADO:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> **QUE PUEDO ESTAR HACIENDO MAL? GRACIAS.**

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el error puede venir por la variable que usas en el código de la clase css: pageTotal. Prueva a modificar tu código:

```
.page-number:after { 
  content: "Página " counter(page) " de " counter(pageTotal);
}
```

por este:

```
.page-number:after { 
    content: "Página " counter(page) " de " counter(pages);
}
```

Saludos!

Comment: Intente eso, pero no me funciona, debo de importar lago?

Answer (score 0):

Usando Dompdf y esto, me funciono.

```
$canvas = $dompdf->get_canvas();
$canvas->page_text(515, 86.5, "Página {PAGE_NUM} de {PAGE_COUNT}", null, 10, array(0,0,0));
```